# Can user buy NFT without external wallet

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

This is a client request I got. The client is having a platform where he sells NFTs as tickets for events. The client needs all users to have a internal wallet that is within the application so that the user doesn't have to install any wallet, also the client don't want the user to pay for any transaction of the NFT like buying, selling, transferring  and minting. I want to know is it possible to pay the transaction fee for all the transaction form a single wallet.

Example: say a user is buying a NFT in address1 from address2 is it possible to pay transaction fee for this from address address3?

Answer (score 0):

> lso the client don't want the user to pay for any transaction of the NFT like buying, selling, transferring and minting.

Generally this is not possible. In the future, it will be possible with [account abstraction](https://ethereum.org/en/roadmap/account-abstraction/).

However if the client is running their own NFT platform and create their own NFT smart contracts, they can create any logic for it, including paying all the transactions from a single wallet. However it might or might not be compatible with the current Ethereum ecosystem, including wallets, blockchain explorer of the blockchain itself.